# How to find number of times you change a list to get from one list to another in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I want to be able to find the number of times to change one list to another.
An example is if I start out with the list [5, 1, 3, 2, 4], but want to change it to the list [4, 5, 2, 1, 3] by taking an element and moving it a number of positions to the left, where it then shifts some other elements to the right.
For example,
5 1 3 2 4
Move the "4" four positions to the left to get -> 4 5 1 3 2
Then move the "2" two positions to the left to get -> 4 5 2 1 3

My attempt at the code was to find the index changes with:

```
n = int(input())
inp = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
out = [int(x) for x in input().split()]

ind = []
for i in range(n):
  ind.append(inp.index(i+1)-out.index(i+1))

print(ind)
```

But then I dont know how to proceed. i also attempted the code

```
def min(x, y):
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(x)):
        if x[i] != y[i]:
            count += 1
            x.insert(y.index(x[i]), x.pop(i))
    return count
```

but then that also didnt work because it didnt pass some of the test cases. Does anyone have a working code for this?

Comment: It is not related to python, it is related to dynamic programming algorithm

Comment: ohh if its dynamic programming, what would be the python code?

Comment: do you want the minimum moves required to get from list A to list B?

Comment: yes, and the moves can only be to the left

Answer (score 0):

```
def changer_counter (l1,l2):
  count = 0
  for i in l1:
    if l1.index(i) <= l2.index(i):
      continue
    else:
      count += (l1.index(i)-l1.index(l2[l2.index(i)+1]))
  return count

print(changer_counter(l1,l2))
```

Comment: could you explain this because i dont think it works for most of the test cases..

Comment: For your example lists I thought that if index of the element in the first list is bigger or equals in the second list it means it moves to the right so it doesn't matter for us. On the other hand if element's index is smaller than the first list this means it moves left in this case I look up the right most element's index of that element in the first list. So I can figure out how many positions it moves. and add up to count variable their indices' difference in terms of the first list.